# TMainMenu build menu item dynamic

Tags: delphi, menu, menuitem

On my system , the main menu is fully dynamic, is builded from data in the database.

I have a specific situation where some menu items need to be assembled before being displayed.

Let's assume that my menu has the following main items:

**Files - Customer - *Reports* - About**

When I click in **Reports** menu item must assemble the items before they are displayed.

I did an analysis of the code in TMainMenu, TMenu and TMenuItem class. Unfortunately I have not found a simple solution to the problem.

Exist a way to create these items before being displayed?

Comment: Probably you will have to replace your TMainMenu with some other implementation. Like TActionMainMenuBar or menu from SpTBXLib.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a trick you can use. You need to add one dummy `TMenuItem` under **Reports** and set its `Visible` property to `False`. Then add `OnClick` event to **Reports** item and do your populating logic there. Before you add new items you have to delete existing ones, but you should leave your dummy item intact.

Something like:

```
procedure TForm1.ReportItemClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TMenuItem;
  I: Integer;
begin
  // Delete all items but first - dummy - one
  for I := ReportItem.Count - 1 downto 1 do
    ReportItem.Items[I].Free;

  Item := TMenuItem.Create(ReportItem);
  Item.Caption := 'abc';
//  Item.OnClick := ...
//  or
//  Item.Action := ...
  ReportItem.Add(Item);

  Item := TMenuItem.Create(ReportItem);
  Item.Caption := '123';
//  Item.OnClick := ...
//  or
//  Item.Action := ...
  ReportItem.Add(Item);
end;
```

Comment: Instead of having the invisible item, you could also add this logic one level higher, so on a click on *Customer*. But your solution is nicer, because it doesn't regenerate the item if you need another submenu than Reports.

Comment: @GolezTrol If I understood correctly Reports is Item of Main Menu, not Customers. If it is Item in Customer then your logic can be applied too.

Comment: Ah, I didn't interpret it like that, but reading again I think you're right. Well, that still makes your answer a good answer.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar. Thanks for your sample and trick. I use your idea and work perfect in my process.

Answer (score 0):

Lets Suppose that you have an DS (TDataSet) how load all your data reports. And in the moment that you drop Reports Menu you can call UpdateMenuReport.

```
type
TMenuArray = array of TMenuItem;

var MyMenu: TMenuArray;

procedure TMain.MyClickPopupMenu(Sender: TObject);
begin
    case TMenuItem(TMenuItem(Sender).Parent).Tag of
        // do Something
    end;
end;


procedure TMain.UpdateMenuReport;
    procedure InitMyMenu(var AMenu: TMenuArray);
    var i: Integer;
    begin
      if Length(AMenu)>0 then for i:= 0 to Length(AMenu)-1 do AMenu[i].Free;
      SetLength(AMenu, 0);
    end;
var j, i: integer;
begin
    InitMyMenu(MyMenu);
    Reports.Clear;
    if DS.Active and (DS.RecordCount > 0) then
    begin
        SetLength(MyMenu, DS.RecordCount);
        for i:= 0 to DS.RecordCount-1 do
        begin
            MyMenu[i] := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
            MyMenu[i].Name := 'Reports_'+ IntToStr(i);
            MyMenu[i].Caption := DS.FieldByname('NOM_REPORT').AsString;
            MyMenu[i].Tag := DS.FieldByname('ID').AsInteger;
            MyMenu[i].OnClick := MyClickPopupMenu;
        end;
    end;
end;
```